# Representation of Strictly Proper Scoring Rule for Multiclasss Classificaiton

Tags: loss-function, scoring

I am working on a classification problem, using features $\mathbf{x}$ to predict a target variable $y \in \mathbb{N}_0$. By a *strictly proper scoring rule* I mean a loss function $\ell(y,\hat{y})$ for which given any input $\mathbf{x}$, the *unique* minimizer of the expected loss is
$$\operatorname{arg\,min}_{\hat{y}} \mathbb{E}_{y|\mathbf{x}} \left[\ell(y,\hat{y}) \right]=\mathbb{E}_{y|\mathbf{x}}[y|\mathbf{x}].
$$
In other words, the loss incentivizes one to predict the expected value of the target variable, given the features. It is known that the squared error loss $$ \ell(y, \hat{y})=(y-\hat{y})^2$$
satisfies this property. Furthermore, if we restrict the target variable to binary classification $y \in \{0,1\}$, then the [Schervish representation theorem](https://sites.stat.washington.edu/raftery/Research/PDF/Gneiting2007jasa.pdf) gives all strictly proper scoring rules as integrals involving a nonnegative weight function $W$:
$$  \ell(y,\hat{y}) = y \int_{\hat{y}}^1 (1-p) {W}(p) \mathrm{d}p + (1-y) \int_0^{\hat{y}} p {W}(p)\mathrm{d}p = \begin{cases} \int_{\hat{y}}^1 (1-p) {W}(p) \mathrm{d}p & y = 1 \\ \int_0^{\hat{y}} p {W}(p) \mathrm{d}p & y=0 \end{cases} . $$
For example $W(p)=2$ gives the squared error loss, while $W(p)=(p(1-p))^{-1}$ gives log loss.

I am interested in similar representations for more than 2 classes, particularly when the target variable domain is $\mathbb{N}_0=\{0,1,2,\dots\}$. Thanks.

Comment: Would you kindly add a list of explicit questions? Are you looking for a Schervish representation theorem for multiple classes?

Comment: @Ggjj11 Yes, I want an analogue of the Schervish representation theorem for multiple classes. I.e. a characterization of all loss functions whose expected value is minimized at the conditional label mean. Ideally the set of labels I want is {0,1,2,...} as it contains all finite label sets as sub-cases.

Comment: As this is about mathematical statistics, the question might be a better fit on [Cross Validated (Statistics) Stack Exchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com), even if the topic isn’t strictly outside the purview of Data Science.

Answer (score 0):

For m classes 1 vs all:

$((y(i)* \int_1^{y_i}(1-p) W(p) dp) + \sum_0 ^{ m-1}((1-y) \int_{y_i}^0 pW(p)/(m-1) dp))$

Comment: Your formulas does not make sense, please provide context and define the symbols